# finding common navigational paths / central nodes within a graph

Tags: algorithms, weighted-graphs, directed-graphs

I have a directed weighted graph representing street (edges weighted by distance) and street intersections (nodes).

Using this graph, I would like find central nodes that a person might find themselves traveling between. For example, I would expect nodes near bridges to have high centrality.

What algorithms might I use to find key route-planning nodes in `< O(n^2)`?

*This excludes betweenness centrality, though, some sort of modified betweenness centrality might be possible*